# Using fragments and BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am creating a shopping list app and was thinking of using `BottomNavigationBar` for it, so the three components of the bar will be **List**, **Done**, and **Manage Categories** or something.

Would this be a good way to go about my shopping list app? Would it work if I wanted it so if the user ticked of `CheckBoxes` in the **List** fragment, those items would move to the **Done** `fragment`? Or should I just use separate `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Activity` with `FrameLayout` as a container for `Fragments` and `BottomNavigationBar`. Don't use multiple `Activities` in this case, it's not good practice.

What about checking boxes and sending information between fragments? You can save info to .txt file, some database (`Room` or `Realm` for example) or keep that information inside `Activity` and just send it to `Fragment` while creating them.